# Mysql Query to find specific rows for which the particular column value don't exist

Tags: mysql, rows, records

I'm in a very complex situation. I know it can be possible with an sql to achieve my goal. Here what is I'm trying to achieve:

I've just one table named 'data'

I've 4 columns having names orderDate, orderID, orderDescription & orderType

There are 4 types of 'orderType' values exist in my table which are Order, Refund, Returned, Adjustment. The orderid would remain same for each 'OrderType' if any of this case happens.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to filter my data as follows.

Select only those orderID records for which the column 'orderType' value (Returned & Adjustment) don't exist in the table.

I'm really looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select orderid
from data
group by orderid
having sum(ordertype in ('Returned', 'Adjustment')) = 0
   and sum(ordertype = 'Refund') > 0 
   and sum(ordertype = 'Order') > 0
```

or just

```
select orderid
from data
group by orderid
having sum(ordertype not in ('Refund', 'Order')) = 0
and count(distinct ordertype) = 2
```

Comment: thanks for quick response Juergen. I tried it and it worked as per my requirement but what I'm noticing that a record for orderType  'Refund' and orderType 'Order' exists in my table, it is just showing one record for a particular orderType. I want if the orderID is same for both order types 'Refund' & 'Order' both should display

Comment: can you please tell me how can I get both the records ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want. But can't you just use `having sum(ordertype in ('Refund', 'Order')) = 0`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't clear my question. I just wanted to retrieve all those orderIDs for which orderType (Returned & Adjustment) don't exist. I want to retrieve all the other orderType (Orders & Refund) records to display for a particular orderid. However, it is just retrieving only a single record either orderType 'Refund' or 'Order' not the both

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer. You want records having `Order` **AND** `Refund`but not the other two values.